# Dimension of spheres in sphere bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm working on this problem from section 4.2 of Hatcher's [*Algebraic Topology*](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf):

> Show that if $S^k\to S^m\to S^n$ is a fiber bundle then $k=n-1$ and $m=2n-1$.

By counting dimensions, we have $m=n+k$, and if I assume that $k<n$ the problem is not too difficult. But, this assumption on $k$ is not stated in the problem. Is there a clean way to show that $k<n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $k > 0$.

The long exact sequence in homotopy gives

$$\dots \to \pi_n(S^{n+k}) \to \pi_n(S^n) \to \pi_{n-1}(S^k) \to \pi_{n-1}(S^{n+k}) \to \dots$$

As $n < n + k$, $\pi_n(S^{n+k}) = 0$ and $\pi_{n-1}(S^{n+k}) = 0$, so $\pi_n(S^n) \cong \pi_{n-1}(S^k)$. We know $\pi_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, so $\pi_{n-1}(S^k) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $n - 1 \geq k$, i.e. $n > k$.

For $k = 0$, the only fiber bundle (or even fibration) is $S^0 \to S^1 \to S^1$ - see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2231390/39599). In this case we also have $k = n -1$ and $m = 2n-1$.

Comment: can you explain why is $k>0$?