# Can $S^0 \to S^n \to S^n$ become a fiber bundle when $n>1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fiber-bundles

As we know, $S^0\to S^n \to \mathbb RP^n$ is a fiber bundle with the usual covering space projection. I wonder if we can construct a projection $S^n \to S^n$ such that $S^0 \to S^n \to S^n$ becomes a fiber bundle.

I need this result to complete the proof in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040823/dimension-of-spheres-in-sphere-bundles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long exact sequence in homotopy gives

$$\dots \to \pi_1(S^n) \to \pi_0(S^0) \to \pi_0(S^n) \to \pi_0(S^n) \to 0.$$

If $n = 0$, then we get an exact sequence $0 \to \pi_0(S^0) \to \pi_0(S^0) \to \pi_0(S^0) \to 0$, but this is impossible so $n > 0$. Then $\pi_0(S^n) = \pi_0(S^n) = 0$, so $\pi_1(S^n)$ surjects onto $\pi_0(S^0) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$. As $\pi_1(S^n) = 0$ for $n \neq 1$, we see that if an example exists, then we must have $n = 1$.

Such an example exists. The map $S^1 \to S^1$, $z \mapsto z^2$ is a double covering, i.e. a fibre bundle $S^0 \to S^1 \to S^1$.

Comment: Somewhat easier: a fiber bundle with fiber $S^0$ is a double cover, and (connected) double covers exist iff the base has fundamental group with a subgroup of index $2$. But $S^n$ is simply connected when $n \ge 2$ so there's no such subgroup.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Nice. That's a much better argument.

Comment: Well, it's not so different: exactness of the long exact sequence in homotopy at $\pi_0(S^0)$ here means precisely that the monodromy action of $\pi_1(S^n)$ on a connected double cover has to be transitive, hence corresponds to a subgroup of index $2$.